# Supervised Learning Approach for Aspect Extraction

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm developing an aspect-level sentiment analysis project for online travel reviews of travel domain.

I have a human annotated dataset that has labelled aspect terms, and aspect categories along with their sentiment polarity.

For example;

```
Sentence:

This beach was a wonderful time for a day party  it had a fun crowd and has a big bar with a great atmosphere. The food was delicious too.
```

The above sentence has the following **aspect terms** labelled;

```
{party#positive C} {crowd#positive C} {bar#positive C} {food#positive C}
```

And the following **aspect categories**;

```
{entertainment#positive C} {accommodation#positive C}
```

I want to try a `supervised learning` approach to train a model to classify aspect terms from sentences.

I'm using `Stanford CORENLP` library. But confused as to how the training data format should be? and what is the best approach to take.

I have seen people using `IOB notation` to format training data to train `NER` systems. Can I use a similar method to get this done? As in, how do I format my training data file to get aspect terms as mentioned above from an input sentence?

If someone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate that a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be tackled by breaking it down to smaller subtasks. A possible pipeline approach may be:

1. The first stage is aspect term extraction which will identify aspect terms in the raw text. This too can be broken down to two  subtasks. Firstly your system will need to label tokens in text that are aspect terms. Let's call the these labelled tokens aspect term mentions. This is called **Named Entity Recognition** (NER). Next, if you have a pre-defined set of aspect term classes, the systems will need to link the aspect term mentions found in the previous task to those classes. This is called **Entity Linking**. It's worth noting that from the example that you give  the labelled dataset is not yet suitable for the above tasks as the labels are not anchored in text. You may be able to create a suitable dataset by guessing which tokens in text do your given labels correspond to. This is similar to the **Distant Supervision** work.
2. The next task is aspect term sentiment classification. **Convolutional Neural Networks** have been used for sentence and document sentiment classification but they can probably be adapted for your purposes if at the input you provide a marker for which tokens are being classified. This is called a position embedding in this work: http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~thien/pubs/vector15.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you please elaborate on why the dataset is not suitable in current format? In which format  should it be in?

Comment: For training a NER model you will need a dataset with the entities marked in text. The IOB notation is one way to do that. To create a such a dataset you can try aligning the words from you labels to text by string matching. I am not sure how well this will work though. It really depends on what your labels are. Are they classes or are they extracted words from the text? If it's the latter then you will almost always be able to find were they are in text.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Sava. Actually, the aspect terms are words that are extracted from raw text by human annotators. By utilizing the string matching mechanism you suggested, I guess it can be done. Apart from IOB notation, is there any other notation?

Comment: There is a some info on page 13 of [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.0398v1.pdf) paper which is also a good paper to read if you are starting with NLP.